# How to create list of files from the ls command?

Tags: python, linux

I have a problem to create a list fo file starting from alpha* inside a give path...I try do do something like this:

```
subprocess.call( 'ls ' + self.source_paths, + ' alpha*'  , shell=True )
```

**where `self.source_paths` is a file containing this row:** `server:home/marco/Codes/New/NewCodes/iqcos_cavg_75.95/`
(where server is a cluster's ip in which i run my simulations)
But python does not accept this and gives me back:

```
ls server:/home/marco/Codes/New/NewCodes/iqcos_cavg_75.95/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "array.py", line 86, in <module>
    epd = enstropyProductionData()
  File "array.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.createFileList() 
  File "array.py", line 53, in createFileList
    call ( print('ls ' + self.source_paths[0]) , shell=True ) 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 339, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1424, in _execute_child
    args = list(args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How can do this thing wihtout any mistake in the code?

Comment: You can't concatenate a string and a file object. So if `self.source_parths` is really a file, you need to read its content first.

Comment: In general, `ls` should not be used for this job at all -- [not even in shell scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: using `fo = readline(self.source_paths)` I got an error since I read the file using  `parser.add_argument('-s' ,'--sources' `

Comment: Why don't you use Python's [OS library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) ?

Comment: Wait. What exactly is `self.source_paths`? Is it the _name_ of a file? Is it an actual open file object itself? Clarifying this kind of thing is part of why providing a [mre] is important.

Comment: yes is a file containing path ! just one line `server:/home/marco/Codes/New/NewCodes/iqcos_cavg_75.95`

Comment: Is `server:` a second path? Why is it named `source_paths` _plural_, if it only contains one path? And you still haven't answered if it's a _file name_ or a _file object_.

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't use `ls` at all.

`ls` is [completely unsuited to programmatic use](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Even in a shell script, using it in this way would be incorrect.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pathlib

source_paths = open(sys.argv[1], 'r') # expect a filename on our command line

for path in source_paths:
  path = path.rstrip('\r\n')
  print(f"Searching path {path}")
  for result in pathlib.Path(path).glob('alpha*'):
    print(f" -> Found {result}")
```

Comment: but in this case it is possible the source_path from frist line of file ?

Comment: @Drudoxlebowsky, see edit, which reads the paths from a file.

Answer (score 1):

So I agree with Charles Duffy and that you shouldn't use ls and there are other ways of doing it but here is a solution with popen

```
import subprocess

t = subprocess.Popen('ls ' + self.source_paths + 'alpha*'  , shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = t.communicate()
lslist = stdout.decode("utf-8").split('\n')[:-1]
```

I forgot to add my `t =`

Comment: ...so, this probably needs to be something more like `subprocess.Popen('ls ' + ' '.join([shlex.quote(path + '/alpha*') for path in self.source_paths], shell=True)`, if you're going to in fact stick with using `ls` and `shell=True`.

Comment: (that aid, `ls` adds no value whatsoever here; you'd do better off to do something roughly like `subprocess.Popen('''printf '%s\0' {' '.join([shlex.quote(path+'/alpha*')])}''')`, and then even filenames that contain newlines will work right).

Comment: err, `f'''` above, of course, so the `{...}` contents are expanded as Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I've done but I got this :  python alpha_list_files.py -l l_alpha.txt -s s_alpha.txt

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alpha_list_files.py", line 102, in <module>
    epd = enstropyProductionData()
  File "alpha_list_files.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.createFileList() 
  File "alpha_list_files.py", line 67, in createFileList
    call(['ls', self.source_paths, 'alpha*'], shell=True )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 339, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1482, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

... consider that the source of the file is a server ... for which from shell everithing works fine .. but not in my python script